# How to make UI more responsive for other screen sizes?

Tags: javascript, html, css, responsive-design

I have an html page in which I have a textbox (Type your text) and TextArea list. I need to type into the textbox and then click Add button so that whatever is there in textbox goes to my TextArea list. I need to type in this below format in the textbox.

```
Name=Value
```

This textbox will be used by the user to quickly add Name Value pairs to the list which is just below that textbox. let's say if we type `Hello=World` in the above textbox and click add, then in the below list, it should show as

```
Hello=World
```

And if we again type `ABC=PQR` in the same textbox, then in the below list, it should show like this so that means it should keep adding new Name Value pair just below its original entry.

```
Hello=World
ABC=PQR
```

But if the syntax is incorrect like if it is not in Name=Value pair then it should not add anything to the list and instead show a pop up that wrong input format. Names and Values can contain only alpha-numeric characters. I also have three more buttons `Sort by name`, `Sort by value` and `Delete` button. Once I click either of these buttons, then it should sort entries in TextArea list using either name or value and delete entries as well. Now I have all above things working fine without any issues.

Here is my [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/56hs2nmn/7/). I need to use plain HTML, CSS and Javascript, I don't want to use any library yet as I want to keep it simple as I am still learning. Now I am trying to see whether we can make UI more responsive like the UI should adjust based on what screen size is viewing it. For example, if viewed on a mobile phone (i.e. Android or iPhone), the page should automatically adjust to present the layout in a better way. This also applies to re-sizing the browser on desktop, and viewing the page on a tablet.

What are the changes I need to make in my CSS or HTML to make it more responsive? Any improvements I can make here? Since my UI is very simple so there should be some easy way or some improvements I can make here.

Below is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Test</title>

<style type="text/css">
.main{
    background:white;
    padding: 35px;
    border-radius: 5px;
}

#my-text-box {
    font-size: 18px;
    height: 1.5em;
    width: 585px;
}
#list{
    width:585px;
    height:300px;
    font-size: 18px;
}
.form-section{
    overflow:hidden;
    width:700px;
}
.fleft{float:left}
.fright{float:left; padding-left:15px;}
.fright button{display:block; margin-bottom:10px;}

html, body {
    height: 100%;
    font-family: "Calibri";
    font-size: 20px;
}

html {
    display: table;
    margin: auto;
}

body {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
    background-color: #5C87B2;
}
</style>

<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
document.getElementById('add').onclick = addtext;
function addtext() {
    var nameValue = document.getElementById('my-text-box').value;
      if (/^([a-zA-Z0-9]+=[a-zA-Z0-9]+)$/.test(nameValue)){
        var x = document.getElementById("list");

        var option = document.createElement("option");
        option.text = nameValue;
        x.add(option);
    }
    else
        alert('Incorrect Name Value pair format.');
}
document.getElementById('btnDelete').onclick = deleteText;
function deleteText(){
    var myList = document.getElementById('list');
    var i;
    for (i = myList.length - 1; i>=0; i--) {
    if (myList.options[i].selected) {
      myList.remove(i);
    }
  }
}

document.getElementById('sortByValue').onclick = sortByValue;
function sortByValue(){
    var myList = document.getElementById('list');
    var values = new Array();
    for (var i=0;i<myList.options.length;i++) {
        values[i] = myList.options[i].text;
    }
      values.sort(function(a, b){
            if(a != "" && b != ""){
                return a.split('=')[1].localeCompare(b.split('=')[1])
            } else {
                return 0
            }
        });

   clearList(myList);
   fillList(myList, values);
}
document.getElementById('sortByName').onclick = sortByName;
function sortByName(){
    var myList = document.getElementById('list');
    var values = new Array();
    for (var i=0;i<myList.options.length;i++) {
        values[i] = myList.options[i].text;
    }
      values.sort(function (a, b){
            if(a != "" && b != ""){
                return a.split('=')[0].localeCompare(b.split('=')[0])
            } else {
                return 0
            }
        });

    clearList(myList);

    fillList(myList, values);
}

function clearList(list) {
    while (list.options.length > 0) {
        list.options[0] = null;
    }
}

function fillList(myList, values){
    for (var i=0;i<values.length;i++) {
        var option = document.createElement("option");
        option.text = values[i];
        myList.options[i] = option;
    }
}
</script>

</head>

<body>
<div class = 'main'>
    <h3>Test</h3>

    <label for="pair">Type your text</label></br>
    <div class="form-section">
        <div class="fleft">
            <input type='text' id='my-text-box' value="Name=Value" />
        </div>
        <div class="fright">
            <button type="button" id='add' onclick='addtext()'>Add</button>
        </div>
    </div>
    <label for="pairs">Name/Value Pair List</label></br>
    <div class="form-section">
        <div class="fleft">
           <select id="list" multiple></select>
        </div>
        <div class="fright">
            <button type="button" id='sortByName' onclick='sortByName()'>Sort by name</button>
            <button type="button" id='sortByValue' onclick='sortByValue()'>Sort by value</button>
            <button type="button" id='btnDelete' onclick='deleteText()'>Delete</button>
            <button type="button">Show XML</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you remove the `</br>`s from the source, because I find it hard to concentrate on the other issues while those are in there. Tunnel vision.

Comment: Done, deleted all `</br>`s from source.

Answer (score 0):

W3 have a number of resources on responsive web design:

http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_responsive.asp
http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_responsive_intro.asp

Without using PHP to detect the browser/user agent, your responsive design will typically involve ensuring the site is more fluid and flowing, allowing for changing browser widths (as in the first example above) and/or by delivering differing stylesheets depending on the viewport size and media type in CSS (second example).